# Git Branches Can I test it in the browser?

Tags: git, magento

this is a more of a guidance question:

I've a local git repo which I then push to public_html/stage in siteground server.

for each feature or bug issue I create a different branch and merge it with the master branch. I then push it to the server.

I want to know if there is anyway I can test different branches in the browser url just like i can test the master branch.

So, if I go to http://stage.tista.co.uk/ I can see the magento installation (which is my master branch).

Is there a way I can also check different branches under the stage repo by going to a url?

I did some googling but I didn't find anything.

I need a way to test the feature/bug branches to make sure it works before merging them with the master or pushing it to live. thanks

Comment: Do you have a local apache server to test with?

Answer (score 0):

If your code lives in your Git repository, and you have multiple branches, and you're capable of reproducing/rebuilding your code base with a few commands, then testing the branch you're working on should be a matter of doing the following:

- `git checkout <branch_name>`,
- Perform your build steps here, including running unit tests,
- Open your web browser and navigate to your test URL.

There *may* be tools out there that allow you to, with some configuration, test any branch you have in the wild with a few clicks of a button, but Git's role is only to check out the branch.  It doesn't involve itself with the building of the project, nor does it add any special hooks to allow it to do so.

Comment: Thanks :) do you happen to know any such tools?

Comment: Nope.  But, you shouldn't need them - they're doing exactly what I'm describing under the hood.

Comment: Perhaps I am not getting the clear picture for not having adequate experience/knowledge of #2 above. Also what would be my test url? Say if my branch is called feature_01 can i specify during the build phase on which url I can check this feature_01?

Comment: No.  Don't conflate Git with the way your application is deployed; it has no part in it.  What you do to build your project on `master` is the same thing you do to build your project on the other branches.  The configuration shouldn't change.